# Cannot run script properly with my custom plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, javascript

I'm pretty new with wordpress developing. What I'm trying to do is to add javascript to my plugin. It seems to be loaded, because when I'm console loging something like 'test' it works fine. But when I'm trying to query anything (for example document.querySelector('#only-for-test')) or even ('body'), it gives me back 'null'...

```
function addThemeStyles() {
  wp_enqueue_style('style_file' , plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'plugin_styles.css');
}

function addThemeScript() {
  wp_enqueue_script('js-file', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'plugin_pj_script.js');
}

function todoPJ_enqueueBootstrapCSS()
{
    // CSS
    wp_register_style('prefix_bootstrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('prefix_bootstrap');
}

function testFunction() {
  // $test = plugin_dir_path('styles.css');

  return '
  <div class="another-test-file" id="only-for-test">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <h1>Another Hello World!</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>';
}


add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addThemeStyles');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addThemeScript');
add_action('wp_head', 'todoPJ_enqueueBootstrapCSS');

add_shortcode('example', 'testFunction');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, maybe it will help someone - probably, my script was loading on the header, so html was loading after script fired. What I did was adding those few parameters, where this last 'true' is the most important (moves script to footer). Hope this helps to anyone

```
  wp_enqueue_script('js-file', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'/js/plugin_pj_script.js', '', '1.0.0', true);
```